# How can I splice these two laptop power supply cords together?

Tags: power-supply, repair

My laptop power supply cord stopped working. I had it wired directly into the "plug-and-play" plug that plugs into the motherboard of my laptop due to not being able to get a replacement power jack. Don't worry I'm not a noob at these types of things. It worked fine for months but was an older cord and I think it was just the boxes time to go out. I have another laptop power supply cord that is the right output that I want to splice onto the part of the cord I have coming out of the laptop. (details can be seen in photos I will be attaching) I already know the color coding of the cord from the laptop; 1)Brown=Ground/Hot, 2)Blue=Neutral/Info, the cord I am splicing is 1)ground wires surrounding the 2)neutral/info white inner wire. I guess what I am asking (purely for a second opinion incase I am not as knowledgeable as I believe about this instance) is when splicing the two together, 1)brown goes to the 1)surrounding ground wires, and 2)blue goes to the 2)center wire(s)?

I have a lot of experience with electronics and building/repairing/etc them, but it is always better to get outside opinions, especially in this case. The difference between this case and all my other experience with splicing cables/wiring is that this is the first time that I didn't have the "right" replacement materials (meaning usually I can find an identical replacement cord/whatnot and don't have to use two different cord assemblies).

[image: cord already attached to laptop]

[image: Other Cord]

Comment: *"I'm not a noob at these types of things"* -- Your descriptions of *"1)Brown=Ground/Hot, 2)Blue=Neutral/Info"* and *"1)ground wires ... 2)neutral/info wire"* for DC power wiring indicates an inflated sense of worth.

Comment: Please don't take offence - but how old are you? I wonder if you are too young to know how much you don't know - and if you are overestimating your understanding, what you are doing is VERY dangerous.  (Including non obvious things like long exposed AC wires)

Comment: Your proposed ‘solution’ will let all the magic smoke out.. rapidly & terminally. If you survive the experience let it be the first lesson in brown != ‘ground’ ... The rest of your question makes it quite clear you absolutely do not have sufficient knowledge to even be attempting anything to do with wiring.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect and I've noticed it more frequently in older people, unlike what you're implying, @davidgo ;)

Answer (score 2):

You should show the whole cables/boxes. What you are describing looks wrong and dangerous - specifically it looks like you are trying to connect a mains voltage AC cable (blue/brown) to a DC cable (shielded ground + DC signal in white shielding.